Horror mockumentary film from the 90s or 2000s involving a time traveling lake located by an abandoned farmhouse. I believe it was on Amazon Prime
I watched this movie on Prime sometime last year during Halloween but I cannot remember the name of the movie.
It was about a guy and his wife who went to a picnic at this abandoned farmhouse; I think it was abandoned or the family that owned it never showed up to or cared for it, and the guy's wife ended up disappearing when she went down this hill by this lake to grab some food or something the guy threw at her as a joke.
The people in town thought the guy killed his wife, so this camera crew decided to do a documentary on the guy years later to prove he either was or was not a killer. The guy keeps insisting the wife just disappeared and they go to the farmhouse land but nothing happens.
As the camera crew continues to investigate, they find some odd occurrences have occurred with one of the townspeople claiming his cow went missing on that land by the lake. He figured the cow was stolen by the family that lived there, since they never left the house, and told everyone in town about them being thieves causing everyone to stay away from the family's place.
The people doing the documentary eventually come across one of the family members who lived in that house and that person claims her sister was playing one day outside and disappeared, by the lake so the family figured it must've been a town person that kidnapped and killed her or she drowned in the lake. The crew has the lake searched and nothing happens, then the family member they found tells them about something specific happening within the house whenever someone would go near the lake when they were younger, their parents would end up acting different whenever they'd come home from being near the lake which they always thought was weird.
Eventually, the guy's wife and that little girl were found inside the walls of the abandoned farmhouse, with the wife's skeleton being a few years older, meanwhile, the little girl's skeleton being like 40 years old or something.
I can't remember the name of this movie but I remember the entire time being so-so with it until the end, which had me going "Wow, this was really entertaining; I did not see that coming."

How did time travel feature in the plot? Something to do with the ageing of the bodies?

If you can no longer log in with the account you used to post this question, please create a new account, then merge your accounts by following the instructions provided here. Once the accounts are merged, you'll regain the ability to post comments in this thread, edit this question without approval from other users, and mark an answer as accepted, if one is posted.
